# Very slow framerate with AVFoundation and Metal in MacOS

Tags: macos, avfoundation, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to adapt Apple's [AVCamFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream) sample to MacOS. The filtering appears to work, but rendering the processed image through Metal gives me a framerate of several seconds per frame. I've tried different approaches, but have been stuck for a long time.

This is the project [AVCamFilterMacOS](https://github.com/jakeva/AVCamFilterMacOS) - Can anyone with better knowledge of AVFoundation with Metal tell me what's wrong? I've been reading the documentation and practicing getting the unprocessed image to display, as well as rendering other things like models to the metal view but I can't seem to get the processed CMSampleBuffer to render at a reasonable framerate.

Even if I skip the renderer and send the videoPixelBuffer to the metal view directly, the view's performance is pretty jittery.

Here is some of the relevant rendering code I'm using in the controller:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    processVideo(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
}
```

func processVideo(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
    if !renderingEnabled {
      return
    }

```
guard let videoPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer),
  let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer) else {
    return
}

if !self.videoFilter.isPrepared {
  /*
   outputRetainedBufferCountHint is the number of pixel buffers the renderer retains. This value informs the renderer
   how to size its buffer pool and how many pixel buffers to preallocate. Allow 3 frames of latency to cover the dispatch_async call.
   */
  self.videoFilter.prepare(with: formatDescription, outputRetainedBufferCountHint: 3)
}

// Send the pixel buffer through the filter
guard let filteredBuffer = self.videoFilter.render(pixelBuffer: videoPixelBuffer) else {
  print("Unable to filter video buffer")
  return
}

self.previewView.pixelBuffer = filteredBuffer
}
```

And from the renderer:

```
func render(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    if !isPrepared {
        assertionFailure("Invalid state: Not prepared.")
        return nil
    }

    var newPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, outputPixelBufferPool!, &newPixelBuffer)
    guard let outputPixelBuffer = newPixelBuffer else {
        print("Allocation failure: Could not get pixel buffer from pool. (\(self.description))")
        return nil
    }
    guard let inputTexture = makeTextureFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, textureFormat: .bgra8Unorm),
        let outputTexture = makeTextureFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: outputPixelBuffer, textureFormat: .bgra8Unorm) else {
            return nil
    }

    // Set up command queue, buffer, and encoder.
    guard let commandQueue = commandQueue,
        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(),
        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() else {
            print("Failed to create a Metal command queue.")
            CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache!, 0)
            return nil
    }

    commandEncoder.label = "Rosy Metal"
    commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(computePipelineState!)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(inputTexture, index: 0)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(outputTexture, index: 1)

    // Set up the thread groups.
    let width = computePipelineState!.threadExecutionWidth
    let height = computePipelineState!.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup / width
    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSizeMake(width, height, 1)
    let threadgroupsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: (inputTexture.width + width - 1) / width,
                                      height: (inputTexture.height + height - 1) / height,
                                      depth: 1)
    commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)

    commandEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.commit()
    return outputPixelBuffer
}

func makeTextureFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, textureFormat: MTLPixelFormat) -> MTLTexture? {
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)

    // Create a Metal texture from the image buffer.
    var cvTextureOut: CVMetalTexture?
    CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, pixelBuffer, nil, textureFormat, width, height, 0, &cvTextureOut)

    guard let cvTexture = cvTextureOut, let texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(cvTexture) else {
        CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache, 0)

        return nil
    }

    return texture
}
```

And finally the metal view:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    var mirroring = false
    var rotation: Rotation = .rotate0Degrees

    syncQueue.sync {
        pixelBuffer = internalPixelBuffer
        mirroring = internalMirroring
        rotation = internalRotation
    }

    guard let drawable = currentDrawable,
        let currentRenderPassDescriptor = currentRenderPassDescriptor,
        let previewPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer else {
            return
    }

    // Create a Metal texture from the image buffer.
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(previewPixelBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(previewPixelBuffer)

    if textureCache == nil {
        createTextureCache()
    }
    var cvTextureOut: CVMetalTexture?
    CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              textureCache!,
                                              previewPixelBuffer,
                                              nil,
                                              .bgra8Unorm,
                                              width,
                                              height,
                                              0,
                                              &cvTextureOut)
    guard let cvTexture = cvTextureOut, let texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(cvTexture) else {
        print("Failed to create preview texture")

        CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache!, 0)
        return
    }

    if texture.width != textureWidth ||
        texture.height != textureHeight ||
        self.bounds != internalBounds ||
        mirroring != textureMirroring ||
        rotation != textureRotation {
        setupTransform(width: texture.width, height: texture.height, mirroring: mirroring, rotation: rotation)
    }

    // Set up command buffer and encoder
    guard let commandQueue = commandQueue else {
        print("Failed to create Metal command queue")
        CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache!, 0)
        return
    }

    guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else {
        print("Failed to create Metal command buffer")
        CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache!, 0)
        return
    }

    guard let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: currentRenderPassDescriptor) else {
        print("Failed to create Metal command encoder")
        CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache!, 0)
        return
    }

    commandEncoder.label = "Preview display"
    commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState!)
    commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexCoordBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
    commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(textCoordBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
    commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(texture, index: 0)
    commandEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(sampler, index: 0)
    commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4)
    commandEncoder.endEncoding()

    // Draw to the screen.
    commandBuffer.present(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

All of this code is in the linked project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture device delegates don't own the sample buffers they receive in their callbacks, so it's incumbent on the receiver to make sure they're retained for as long as their contents are needed. This project doesn't currently ensure that.

Rather, by calling `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer` and wrapping the resulting pixel buffer in a texture, the view controller is allowing the sample buffer to be released, meaning that future operations on its corresponding pixel buffer are undefined.

One way to ensure the sample buffer lives long enough to be processed is to add a private member to the camera view controller class that retains the most-recently received sample buffer:

```
private var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!
```

and then set this member in the `captureOutput(...)` method before calling `processVideo`. You don't even have to reference it further; the fact that it's retained should prevent the stuttery and unpredictable behavior you're seeing.

This solution may not be perfect, since it retains the sample buffer for longer than strictly necessary in the event of a capture session interruption or other pause. You can devise your own scheme for managing object lifetimes; the important thing is to ensure that the root sample buffer object sticks around until you're done with any textures that refer to its contents.